# Bootstrap grid gives black line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I just started using Bootstrap. From what I've read, this code should execute without any problem:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="page" class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1  col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 ">
            <div id="header"></div>
            <div id="article"></div>
            <div id="footer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Instead while col-lg I get a black line, and md to sm I get full screen.

**CSS**

```
#page {
    background: black;
    width: auto;
    height: 500px;
}
```

`Width: auto` should cover the whole lg-grid size. Why is there something like 10-20px vertical line, and when I shrink the page it becomes full screen?

During `col-sm-12` it should cover the whole page. but during `col-md` it should have 1 grid line offset at the begin, 10 grid lines black and 1 empty at the end.
And during `col-lg`  2 grid offset, 8 grid black and 2 grid empty.

I know container has some preset values, but still, it shouldn't affect the 12 grid system.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't** give cols a width. They have **already** a, from Bootstrap *computed* width. That's the core of the grid system and what makes it responsive.

If you want something to give a width or height do it **within** the col:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-...">
            <div id="page">
                <div id="header"></div>
                <div id="article"></div>
                <div id="footer"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are facing the issue cause you applied css of width:auto for the col-* by using id #page. But bootstrap have a fixed width for every col-* for a certain breakpoints for responsive. So, cause of your "width:auto" its not working for view port width greater then 767px and that is why you are getting just "a black line".

And when the view port is less then 768px, bootstrap removes the width from all col-* which becomes take full width and that is why you are getting full black div for smaller screen/window/viewport.

I'm not sure if i was able to explain it well. So, if you still have question. Just comment.